# Issue in kendo UI's Tabstrip

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using the kendo TabStrip in my sample. I have added the tabs following through documentation. And found events sample at http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tabstrip/events.html

I have tried the same sample in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZrFGX/5/.

My code is looks like this,

```
    function onContentLoad(e) {
        alert("content loaded!");
    }

    $("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip({
        contentLoad: onContentLoad
    });
```

onContentLoad is not even called single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per their documentation:

**contentLoad**
Triggered when content is fetched from an AJAX request.

I don't see any content being fetched via AJAX.

http://jsfiddle.net/qxTMm/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function onContentLoad(e) {
        alert("content loaded!");
    }

    var tabstrip = $("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip({
        select: onContentLoad
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mithrilhall. I didn't see anything like that. Can you point out the documentation where it has briefly defined about "contentLoad".

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip#events-contentLoad